# Detect if files are being dragged, before drop event?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fileapi

Apparently the dragged file list is not available in `dragenter` and `dragover` events for privacy reasons. It's only revealead in the drop event.

Is there some other way I could detect if files are being dragged, and not some dom elements?

Comment: Indeed. "event.dataTransfer.files.count" is zero in all "drag" events except the final "drop". This is really inconvenient.